# Debugging NdisTimedDataHang reported by Driver Verifier

Tags: windbg, ndis, bsod

I have enabled NDIS/WIFI verification flag of my driver in Driver Verifier. This resulted in BSOD for hitting the [ndistimeddatahang](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/ndis-ndistimeddatahang) rule. When I analyzed the dump, I got -

> DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION (c4)
>
> Arguments:
>
> Arg1: 000000000009200f, ID of the 'NdisTimedDataHang' rule
> that was violated.
>
> Arg2: fffff806cd819200, A pointer to the string
> describing the violated rule condition.
>
> Arg3: ffff87862606b110,
> Address of internal rule state (second argument to !ruleinfo).
>
> Arg4:
> ffff87862606b240, Address of supplemental states (third argument to
> !ruleinfo).

When I did [!ndiskd.pendingnbls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ndiskd-pendingnbls), I got the list of NBLs that are currently pending while the dump was taken. To figure out, which NBL has caused the violation, I tried to use [!ruleinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ruleinfo) command with the arguments received in analyzing.

> ruleinfo 0x9200f 0xffff87862606b110 0xffff87862606b240

but Windbg reported the error -

> Failed to read the rule state (check the second argument).

What am I doing wrong ? Is there any way to figure out which NBL failed to complete in 22 seconds which is a requirement for ndistimeddatahang rule ?

Comment: i would suggest getting this query to ntdev list of community.osr.com  you may get a better response from some ms devs like jeffrey tippet   who watch that list

Comment: @blabb Thanks for the suggestion. Posted there. Seems like that community is more active for Windows driver related stuff.